# Code formated with spaces not working after list Items

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Just wondering if this is a bug or as intended:

### Code before List item

```
<- 4 Spaces for code (working)

    <- 8 Spaces for code (working)
```

### Code After List Item

- <- List Item

  <- 4 Spaces for code (not working)

  ```
  <- 8 Spaces for code (working)
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior with [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list).

As the Markdown spec states,

> List items may consist of multiple paragraphs. Each subsequent
>   paragraph in a list item must be indented by either 4 spaces or one
>   tab:
>
> 1. This is a list item with two paragraphs. Lorem ipsum dolor
>      sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam hendrerit
>      mi posuere lectus.
>
>    Vestibulum enim wisi, viverra nec, fringilla in, laoreet
>      vitae, risus. Donec sit amet nisl. Aliquam semper ipsum
>      sit amet velit.
> 2. Suspendisse id sem consectetuer libero luctus adipiscing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, devil is always in the missed details :)